# How to effectively administer huge number of iOS in-app purchaes?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

Is anyone familiar with another way of administering iOS in-app purchases outside of iTunes Connect.  I am looking for a third party tool that will help me submit in-app purchases as I have a huge number and find the administration process very cumbersome.

The solution I am looking for would allow me to batch export a list (along with the required screenshots for each in-app purchase).

If this does not exist, can someone please create it ;)

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the application loader.

Create a tab-separated text file with all the required information and then use the application loader to upload the list of in-apps.